# Why is my content always being shifted to the left within a div?

Tags: jquery, css

Based on this tutorial at:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/

Why does my content always shift to the left and doesn't stay centered?

By this I mean the whole content div starts from the leftmost side of the browser window and then returns back to the center of the website.

Always shifts to the left and then returns to the center.

Initially I had my website all to the left of the browser window and now have decided to move it all to the center. By doing this though, the website is now all centered but when I click on the "features" tab, the jQuery animation which I have not included in the code gets performed from the leftmost of the browser and not the center.

I think there is something in my CSS that is causing it. Also I have left how html head tags on purpose.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--

/** {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}*/

body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: center; /* Center align for IE */
}

#navwrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 113px;
}

#listnav {
    width: 996px;
    height: 59px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #393;
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center align for Good browsers like Firefox, Opera, Netscape */
    text-align: left;
}

#listnav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#listnav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid #990;
    border-bottom: none;
    font-weight: lighter;
    background-color: #9C0;
    background-image: url(images/backtab.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#listnav li a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

li   {
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a  {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#listnav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #71BFEE;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#listnav li a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#listnav li a#current
{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #71BFEE;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}

#nav {
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

#content {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #333;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #990;
    border-bottom-color: #990;
    border-left-color: #990;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 984px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: left;
}

#foot a {
    color: #FF9933;
    float: none;
}
-->
</style>

<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#content").load('home.html');

    $('#nav a').click(function(){
       $("#nav").find("a").removeAttr("id");
       $(this).attr("id" , "current" );
    });

    $('#nav li a').click(function(){  
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href'); 

        $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);  

        function loadContent() {  
            $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())  
        }  
        function showNewContent() {  
            $('#content').show('normal');  
        }  
        return false;
    });

});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="navwrapper">
 <div id="header">
  <img src="images/header.jpg" width="996" height="112" alt="myWebsite" longdesc="http://www.myWebsite.com" />
 </div>
 <div id="listnav">
   <ul id="nav">
     <li><a href="home.html" id="current">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="features.html" >Features</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
 </div>
 <div id="foot">Copyright © 2010 All rights reserved. </div>
</div>
</body>
```

PS Also, how can I turn my header graphic image into a href so when the user clicks on it, goes to the a href url?

Comment: How did this question get an up-vote? There's no possible *answer*... O.o

Comment: In the css that's on the tutorial page there is no where any indication that your div should be in the center.

Comment: Sorry, have now added my code and also, I did my website a bit different to the actual tute. Hope you can spot why it shifts/flicks to the let of the browser and then back to the center. Thanks.

Comment: But you say you have edited the markup and have specifically not included the jQuery, which is the bit that's under question. Just the little bit where you do the actual animation is likely enough to get us started.

Comment: No worries - have now included jQuery component to my original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an artifact of the `hide()`/`show()` animation (since you use a duration) ..

if you try a different animation like `slideUp()`/`slideDown()` it works fine..

***[update]***

The problem in your code is the

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

of the `#content` rule..

it should be at the `#navwrapper` rule which should also not be `100%` but `996px` ... so that the whole site gets centered..

Comment: Thanks for that - unsure then why it works the guy who id the tute?Just wondering, what do I need to do to substitute with slideUp and SlideDown?

Comment: just change `hide('fast',loadContent)` with `slideUp('fast',loadContent)` and `$('#content').show('normal')` with `$('#content').slideDown('normal')`

Comment: thanks Gaby - got it going but thanks anyways. works great now like you said. Still puzzled how the guy in tute got it to work with hide/show? Happy with the slide effects. Thanks.

Comment: @tonsils, just posted the problem with your css... You were centering #content and the rest of the site with two different methods ..

Comment: Thanks Gaby - you were spot on. Thanks for finding the issue with css. All works great now.

Answer (score -2):

Stick your header image inside an Href tag if you want to click it and have it take you to some URL.